# How can I search for a gameObject by Text component's text

Tags: unity-game-engine

I took over some Unity project on my job. It was made by another company and I don't have any information for this project.

They made so many popup on the scene ( 180 over popups ) and popup's name is cannot be identified (ex. popup1, popup2, popup...)

So I cannot find the popup I want. I just know about popup's contents (message and title)

The popup is a Game Object's node and it's on the Hierarchy Tab. Almost popups consists of background (color), Title (text), Contents (text), Button (text).

How can I search for the popup I want? (just use popup's text (title, message))

Visual Studio (search all at Solution) cannot find this and I'd open a Scene.unity file to notepad, and I search popup's text, but it cannot find it!

Comment: Sure but it'll be expensive. Why not just save a ref to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio (search all at Solution) cannot find this and I'd open a Scene.unity file to notepad, and I search popup's text, but it cannot find it!

This would suggest the popup text is in `.prefab` files. You can search those too.

Otherwise, author an editor script that enumerates through the `Selection.activeSelection` components using `GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()`.